# Does setting SSL for Kafka affect Zookeeper communication

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, communication

I know that Zookeeper acts as a Data-Store for Kafka. But what I have been looking to get clear is -

If I set SSL for Kafka then will that affect ***Kafka Broker to Zookeeper communication*** in any way? I mean do I have to make any changes specific to broker-zookeeper communication to not get interupted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple paths for data movement in Kafka

Sounds like you're asking about the Kafka client interaction, which would be setup on the `advertised.listener` addresses as `SSL://...` for example.

But that isn't encrypting data between Kafka and Zookeeper

[According to Confluent docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_ssl.html#zk)

> The version of ZooKeeper that is bundled with Apache Kafka does not support SSL.

And so, assuming that is not outdated, you would need to grab a version of Zookeeper that does, [which isn't a stable version yet](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/ZooKeeper+SSL+User+Guide), [**ZOOKEEPER-2185**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-2125)

That being said, mutiple people have successfully setup Kafka with SSL, but clearly the data over the wire to Zookeeper isn't encrypted. However, there should be no PII-like data going from Kafka to Zookeeper anyway since it is just metadata, if that is the concern.

And note, that is also different from the inter-broker replication protocols, which can be SSL-enabled or not, as well, separately from other Kafka interactions.